# Rails: in controller, a new view is always rendered by `show`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to implement a search function in the controller, which contains "show, new, create, etc..."

I added in `route.rb`:

```
get 'apps/search' => 'apps#search'
```

and in `apps_controller.rb`:

```
def show
  @app_info = App.find(params[:id])
end

def search
  # get parameter and do search function
end
```

but each time when i request the /apps/search?xxx=xxx then it will be rendered by `show`... and then `search?xxx=xxx` is the parameter for method `show`...

should I rather create a new controller for `search`? Or is it possible to implement `search` as my requirements?

Comment: try put `get 'apps/search' => 'apps#search'` before show

Comment: ``` Isn't how you markup code on Stack Overflow

Comment: The request is probably caught by a route further up in your route.rb (it's processed top to bottom), and "search?xxx=xxx" is being recognized as the id.  
Try placing `get 'apps/search' => 'apps#search'` before the route to apps#show

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your routes are incorrectly prioritized - somewhere else in your routes file (before the `get 'apps/search'` line) you have `resources :apps`, which defines a route that matches the same regex as `apps/search`.

Routes match from top to bottom, so if you check the output of `rake routes`, you'll see that your request to `apps/search` is actually matching `apps/:id` - which is the show route of your apps resource.

Either move the `apps/search` route above the `resources :apps` declaration, or alternatively declare your search route as part of the apps resource, eg.

```
resources :apps do
  get :search, on: :collection
end
```

(this will define `apps/search` in the way you want).

For more information on routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score -1):

I think you should edit route.rb as the following:

```
get 'apps/search' => 'apps#show'
```

Answer (score -1):

The Rails' way to "say" search is a new route to the apps controller is using collection. So, for example, supposing you already have a `resources :apps`, you can do:

```
resources :apps do
  get 'search', on: :collection #or you can use another HTTP verb instead of get
end
```

And that would give you:

```
 search_apps GET    /apps/search(.:format)    apps#search
```